BASH Variable set with minus("-")
I'm sorry, I'm a beginner in bash programing.
How to interpret this type of value? How it's work?
What does this do with - (minus) with the variable?
I haven't seen such a function yet. Any other Sample?
DLC=/usr/dlc
JDKHOME=${JDKHOME-$DLC/jdk}
JREHOME=${JREHOME-$DLC/jre}
...


Also see the definitive reference at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02
